# Use audioread or equivalent to play audio in a specific timestamp

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using audioread to play audio, now I would like play the track in different timestamps. What I have so far is:

```
[testSound,Fs] = audioread('test.wav');
sound(testSound,Fs);
```

Is it possible to somehow specify that the audio-track shall start at for example second 5? To be more specific, my audio sample `test.wav` is 45 second long, instead of playing the sound from the beginning, I would like to define where it should start playing.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract out a portion of the signal so that you're starting at the 5 second mark, then play it.  Simply put, you'd start sampling at 5 times the sampling rate as the starting index all the way to the end then play the sound:

```
[testSound,Fs] = audioread('test.wav'); % From your code
beginSecond = 5; % Define where you want to start playing
beginIndex = floor(beginSecond*Fs); % Find beginning index of where to sample
soundExtract = testSound(beginIndex:end, :); % Extract the signal
sound(soundExtract, Fs); % Play the sound
```

Alternatively, since you're using `audioread`, you can actually specify where to start sampling the sound.  You'd use the same logic above and specify the beginning and end of where to sample the sound **in terms of samples**.  However, you'd need to know what the sampling rate is first so you'd have to call `audioread` twice to get the sampling rate, then finally the signal itself:

```
beginSecond = 5; % Define where you want to start playing
[~, Fs] = audioread('test.wav'); % Get sampling rate
beginIndex = floor(beginSecond*Fs); % Find beginning index of where to sample
[soundExtract, ~] = audioread('test.wav', [beginIndex inf]); % Extract out the signal from the starting point to the end of the file
sound(soundExtract, Fs); % Play the sound
```

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks. Just out of curiosity, which solution would you use if you had to choose? The first one your presented, or the second one? And also, which is faster in execution?

Comment: You're very welcome :) Ah, well both have their advantages and disadvantages.  The first one requires that you load the entire signal into memory then remove a part of it.  The second one does the same loading, but you discard all of it so you can get the sampling rate, then you only load in what you need.  The second one will take longer to run as you're calling `audioread` twice, but it's better memory-wise.  The first one is faster.  So use the first one if your file is small, and use the second one if the file is large.  Hope that helps!